# string arg[] causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

So I have a script file we are using in house for testing. I want to use the script for testing over the internet but when I give it a url instead of a ip address it throws a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError,

Why is this and what can I do to fix it

this is the script file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection; 

public class SOAPClient4XG
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    throws Exception
  {
    if (paramArrayOfString.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage:  java SOAPClient4XG http://soapURL soapEnvelopefile.xml [SOAPAction]");


      System.err.println("SOAPAction is optional.");
      System.exit(1);
    } 

    String str1 = paramArrayOfString[0];
    String str2 = paramArrayOfString[1];

    String str3 = "";
    if (paramArrayOfString.length > 2) {
      str3 = paramArrayOfString[2];
    } 

    URL localURL = new URL(str1);
    URLConnection localURLConnection = localURL.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection localHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)localURLConnection;


    FileInputStream localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(str2);

    ByteArrayOutputStream localByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    copy(localFileInputStream, localByteArrayOutputStream);
    localFileInputStream.close();

    byte[] arrayOfByte = localByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


    localHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(arrayOfByte.length));

    localHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    localHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", str3);
    localHttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    localHttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    localHttpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);


    OutputStream localOutputStream = localHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    localOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte);
    localOutputStream.close();



    InputStreamReader localInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(localHttpURLConnection.getInputStream());

    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(localInputStreamReader);

    String str4;

    while ((str4 = localBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(str4);
    } 
    localBufferedReader.close();
  } 


  public static void copy(InputStream paramInputStream, OutputStream paramOutputStream)
    throws IOException
  {
    synchronized ()
    {
      synchronized (paramOutputStream)
      {
        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte['Ā'];
        for (;;) {
          int i = paramInputStream.read(arrayOfByte);
          if (i == -1) break; 
          paramOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

and the bat file used  to run it is this:

```
echo Check in inquiry sending:
java -cp .SOAPClient4XG http://foobar/gotdns/com:8080/axis2/services/HTNGListener checkininquiry.sms http://htng.org/1.1/Listener.Wsdl#ReceiveMessageAsync
```

here is the stack trace:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\accounting\Desktop\springer_miller_docs>java -cp .SOAP
Client4XG http://foobar.gotdns.com:8080/axis2/services/HTNGListener checkinin
quiry.sms http://htng.org/1.1/Listener.Wsdl#ReceiveMessageAsync
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: http://foobar/gotd
ns/com:8080/axis2/services/HTNGListener
```

Comment: What is the full exception text?

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: Please always provide the full stacktrace, because you do not show us which class is not found...

Comment: stack trace added, is that enough for and answer or do you need more, im happy to provide you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with your code but how you're executing it.

Your command line says put the main file onto the class path and then execute main in a class named the first URL.

Leave off -cp and you should be fine (at least from this stack trace).

For reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
URL localURL = new URL(str1);
```

will throw a `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 192.168.0.127` for the argument you're giving it.

[URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) is protocol aware, and you should give it something like `http://soapURL` (as advised by your program itself) instead of a plain IP address.

### edit

not relevant after you changed your question.

Comment: question is the same just with a url instead of an ip, also the .127 was just for illustration i know it does not work